# WFFM Rule Section Is Missing

Tags: xdb, wffm

The Rule section in WFFM is missing. I did some research and changed the `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` to true `<setting name="Xdb.Tracking.Enabled" value="true" />`.
It worked and i am able to see the Rule section but now the site is down :) and throwing the exception.

> Server Error in '/' Application. 
>        Tracker.Current is not initialized  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Tracker.Current
>   is not initialized
>
> Source Error: 
>          An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location
>   of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace
>   below.
>
> Stack Trace: 
>          [InvalidOperationException: Tracker.Current is not initialized] Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.StartTracking.Process(PipelineArgs
>   args) +338 (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +479
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, Boolean failIfNotExists) +36
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.StartAnalyticsPipeline.Run()
>   +372 Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.MvcEvents.RequestBegin.StartTracking.Process(RequestBeginArgs
>   args) +137 (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +479
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +74
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +1028 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +134

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2106.0

The client does not have xDB and we just need a way to enable the rule section in WFFM and the Sitecore version 8.2 rev. 170407 (Update-3).

Any idea? 
Thanks,

Comment: What is `Xdb.Enabled` set to?

Comment: Xdb.Tracking.Enabled is set to true

Comment: Not what I asked - `Xdb.Enabled` is a different setting - what is that set to?

Comment: sorry Xdb.Enabled is set to false as the client does not have Xdb. thanks

Comment: I would raise this as a bug with Sitecore Support. It should be possible to run Rules and Personalisation in that version of Sitecore with xDB=false and Tracking=True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to share with you that this was confirmed as a bug and Sitecore provided a patch to fix it.

public reference number: 190415

Thank you,
Naim